# Using wget to download all files/folders from URL not working?

Tags: wget

So i'm trying to download everything from this directory http://pds-atmospheres.nmsu.edu/PDS/data/mslrem_1001/DATA/ using wget but i can't seem to get it working? It only ever downloads the index.html (which it then removes) and a robot.txt

I've been using this command i've seen around the internet:

`wget -r -np -nH --cut-dirs=3 -R index.html http://pds-atmospheres.nmsu.edu/PDS/data/mslrem_1001/DATA/`

but i only get [this in response](http://pastebin.com/FygS9mBe), when I want all the files in DATA like i were copy a file on explorer :\

Comment: Just wrote my own program in Java using [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) to do the job for this specific directory - disgusting code but whatever ¯\_(ツ)_/¯